# What is the meaning of "turns on" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> Again, the importance
> of fine-tuning **turns on** how narrow or how
> broad the tolerances **around** fundamental constants, while still being consistent with the formation
> of stars and planets, and with sufficient time, **for** the generation
> and evolution of life.

> [What's Fine-Tuning in Cosmology?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjFtFQfHiCs)

What is the meaning of "turns on"? Does it mean "revolve on an axis or hinge"? and does the bold "around" is attached to turns on?
And another question, why in the last part of the sentence there is no verb? does it mean to be "consistent for"?

Comment: Did you transcribe this? There seem to be some words missing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No. If you go to 18:50 to 19:08, you can see the part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, "turns on" means "is decided by":

> turn on
>
> (turn on something) to be the issue, fact, or point that something
> depends on most
>
> *The trial turned on the medical evidence presented by the defence.*

[Turn on (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/turn-on_1#turn-on_1__9)